# Can not send list of props via --spec-vars with jfrog cli

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to upload a file using jfrog cli version 2.48.0. I am using file specs.
If I fill in "props" filed in myUploadSpecs.json and run jf rt u --spec myUploadSpecs.json, it works fine and props are applied to the uploaded artifacts.

```
{
"files": [
{
    "pattern": "${archivePattern}",
    "target": "${target}",
    "props": "env=prod;version=0"
}
]
```

}
but if I want to parameterize this, only first property is applied to the artifact, everything else is ignore.

```
{
"files": [
{
    "pattern": "${archivePattern}",
    "target": "${target}",
    "props": "${props}"
}
]
```

}

```
jf rt u --spec myUploadSpecs.json --spec-vars 'archivePattern=*.tar.gz;target=myrepo/folder/mydata1/;props="env=prod;version=0"'
```

In this case, only env=prod is applied to the artifact while version property is ignored. Am I doing something wrong ?